# Upload e estrutura para armazenamento de imagens no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload, imagem

Comecei a construir um portal, utilizando Laravel, que tem como requisitos: **users, locais pertencentes a users e classificados pertencentes a users**.

Como cada um destes requisitos necessita de imagens, gostaria de saber qual o melhor método para armazenar imagens para cada um destes requisitos e associados a eles.

A minha dúvida está mais assente na estrutura de pastas para armazenar as fotos, e sobre o sistema de upload das imagens em Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Há várias coisas a analisar:

- Seu deploy é feito por alguma ferramenta automatizada? P.e. Capistrano? Se sim, a estrutura deverá ser montada fora da pasta de sua aplicação (que normalmente é feita no diretório public). Pode também apontar o diretório public à uma pasta externa (através de um link simbólico)
- Irá gravar em algum CDN/Cloud files? P.e. Amazon S3? Nesse caso a estrutura é feita por buckets, então terá que pensar meio diferente.

A estrutura poderia ser algo como:

```
shared/usuarios/
shared/usuarios/places
shared/usuarios/classificados
```

No caso da opção 1 seriam pastas, na opção 2, buckets.

Sobre o sistema de uploads não tem segredo, a API para upload é simples de utilizar. Recomendo que salve o caminho desses diretórios em arquivos de configuração, para que seja fácil você mover futuramente, caso precisar.

Segue link das docs: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: Nesse caso, a estrutura não teria de ser:

shared/usuarios/usuario_id/classificados ?

Comment: Sim, pode ser, ou então shared/usuarios/classificados/{usuario_id} assim a pasta usuarios fica mais "limpa". Ai é questão de gosto mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Uso o pacote [codesleeve/stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler/)

Com ele você vai associar imagens a um registro da tabela que deseja colocar uma imagem.

Em geral eu crio uma tabela só para as imagens e vinculo o registro dessa tabela a um registro de outras tabelas, assim posso ter mais de uma imagem vinculada ao registro sem dificuldades.

Um dos diferenciais desse pacote é a possibilidade de enviar sua imagem para um bucket S3 da amazom, oque se torna uma coisa muito boa se você tem que lidar com muitas imagens.

Comment: Obrigado, não conhecia essa forma de armazenas para um bucket S3 Amazon!